# richTextBox gets "extra line" on dataGridView CurrentCellChanged Event

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I've got three events firing here, which allows a user to see the full text of a cell in a datagridview, as they change cells in real time, and can edit the text of the cell or the richTextBox (if the text field is too large).
I'm using:
dataGridView1_CellValueChanged_Handler - To Update SQL and refresh the DGV
dataGridView1_CurrentCellChanged_Handler - To change the text in the RTB
richTextBox2_KeyDown_Handler - To Update SQL and refresh the DGV

The problem is that when editing the text in the RTB, when things go full circle I get an extra line before the cell value from the DGV. I've traced this and can tell the following is occuring:

1. Enter Cell to change in DGV, RTB is updated with value
2. Value is changed in RTB, then press ENTER to commit change
3. DGV CurrentCell [0,0] since it's refreshed and we have a new DGV
4. That value populates into the RTB
5. Programatically, the DGV current cell is reverted to what it was prior to the change
6. RTB is cleared and updated, which had the [0,0] value and instead of the
   new [x,y] value, it has a space in front of the new value.

Not sure how to tackle this issue just yet, any help or suggestions invited.

Sample code below:

---

```
private void handler_dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender,DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){
    if(initialized){
        string query = "";
        string table = tabControl1.TabPages[(tabControl1.SelectedIndex)].Text;
        string column = (string)dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText;
        int sqlID = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
        if(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ValueType.ToString() == "System.DateTime"){
            DateTime valueD = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value);
            query = (@"UPDATE [" + globalDatabase + @"].[dbo].[" + table + @"] SET [" + column +  @"] = '" + valueD +  @"' WHERE [ID] = '" + sqlID + @"'");
        }else if(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ValueType.ToString() == "System.String"){
        string valueS = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
        query = (@"UPDATE [" + globalDatabase + @"].[dbo].[" + table + @"] SET [" + column +  @"] = '" + valueS +  @"' WHERE [ID] = '" + sqlID + @"'");
        }else{
            MessageBox.Show("Unhandled data type in method  handler_dataGridView1_CellValueChanged.");
        }
        WriteSQL(query);
        }else{}
    }
}
private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if(dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value != null){
        MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString().Trim());
        MessageBox.Show(richTextBox2.Text.ToString().Trim());               
        richTextBox2.Clear();
        richTextBox2.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString().Trim();
    }
}
private void richTextBox2_KeyDown_Handler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){
    if(e.KeyValue == 13 && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex != -1 && richTextBox2.Text.ToString().Trim() != dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString().Trim()){
        int    col    = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        int    row    = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        string ID     = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        string table  = tabControl1.TabPages[(tabControl1.SelectedIndex)].Text;
        string column = dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].HeaderText.ToString();
        string value  = richTextBox2.Text.ToString().Trim();
        string query  = @"UPDATE [" + globalDatabase + @"].[dbo].[" + table + @"] SET [" + column + @"] = '" + value + @"' WHERE [ID] = '" + ID + @"'";
        WriteSQL(query);
        RefreshDGV1();
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = this.dataGridView1[col, row];
    }
}
```

---

Starting point, DGV cell is active and text is in RTB

[image]

Value is changed in RTB, and ENTER key is pressed. Value becomes text from DGV's cell [0,0] value on  refresh, which will be changed to become the updated cell[x,y] value.

[image]

What is then remaining is the new value for that cell with an extra line above.

[image]

---

I traced the events and this is basically what happens:

Application Start

```
dataGridView1_CellValueChanged_Handler
dataGridView1_CellValueChanged_Handler
dataGridView1_CellValueChanged_Handler
```

Select Cell to Change

```
dataGridView1_CellValueChanged_Handler
```

Change Value of text in RTB, hit ENTER

```
richTextBox2_KeyDown_Handler
dataGridView1_CellValueChanged_Handler
dataGridView1_CellValueChanged_Handler
dataGridView1_CellValueChanged_Handler
```

---

When I edit the cell from within the cell itself (initiating dataGridView1_CellValueChanged_Handler) I do not get this issue.

Comment: Note: This one line only happens once anywhere in the code.

richTextBox2.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString().Trim();

...and is always prefaced with: richTextBox2.Clear();

Comment: Would it be possible to include a _minimal, complete, and verifiable_ example?

Comment: Added screenshots to description. Due to the sensitive nature of the data, I had to omit a lot of detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the enter key to create a new line, then you should cancel the key press (e.Handled = true; // STOP THE HANDLING)

```
private void richTextBox2_KeyDown_Handler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){
    if(e.KeyValue == 13 && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex != -1 && richTextBox2.Text.ToString().Trim() != dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString().Trim()){
        int    col    = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        int    row    = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        string ID     = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        string table  = tabControl1.TabPages[(tabControl1.SelectedIndex)].Text;
        string column = dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].HeaderText.ToString();
        string value  = richTextBox2.Text.ToString().Trim();
        string query  = @"UPDATE [" + globalDatabase + @"].[dbo].[" + table + @"] SET [" + column + @"] = '" + value + @"' WHERE [ID] = '" + ID + @"'";
        WriteSQL(query);
        RefreshDGV1();
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = this.dataGridView1[col, row];
        e.Handled = true; // STOP THE HANDLING
    }
}
```

Comment: Winner winner, chicken dinner. Thanks so much, sir, I greatly appreciate your help. This was driving me bonkers.